# Python 3.5 ImportError: No module named 'integration'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Have a Python project which I have built in PyCharm, which works if I run from PyCharm, however now I am ready to run it from command line I get the error.

> ImportError: No module named 'integration'

From what I have seen on other similar issues you need to set PYTHONPATH to be the working directory, which I have also done:

```
[nathan@Linux-Macbook integration]$ export PYTHONPATH=/home/nathan/mobileSubscriberDB/integration/integration
[nathan@Linux-Macbook integration]$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/nathan/mobileSubscriberDB/integration/integration
```

Then when I run the command below (Which I am also within the directory specified on the PYTHONPATH), I also get the error straight after:

```
[nathan@Linux-Macbook integration]$ /home/nathan/python_msdb/bin/python /home/nathan/mobileSubscriberDB/integration/integration/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nathan/mobileSubscriberDB/integration/integration/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from integration import bigchain
ImportError: No module named 'integration'
```

Below is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Below is a Copy of my main.py:

```
import threading
import sys
import logging

from integration import bigchain
from integration import config
from integration import log
from integration import rabbitMq, file

def do_something_with_exception():
    exc_type, exc_value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
    print('Handling %s exception with message "%s" in %s' %
          (exc_type.__name__, exc_value, threading.current_thread().name))


class ConsumerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue,  blockchain_host, blockchain_port, rabbit_props, blockchain_props,*args, **kwargs):
        super(ConsumerThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        logger.debug("Data Type: %s" % queue)
        self._queue = queue

        logger.debug("Blockchain Host: %s" % blockchain_host)
        self._blockchain_host = blockchain_host

        logger.debug("Blockchain Port: %s" % blockchain_port)
        self._blockchain_port = blockchain_port

        self._rabbit_props = rabbit_props
        self._blockchain_props = blockchain_props

    def run(self):

        logger.info("Connecting to BigChain DB for %s Data Type" % self._queue)
        bigchaindb = bigchain.BigChain()
        bdb = bigchaindb.connect(self._blockchain_host,
                                 self._blockchain_port)

        private_key = file.File.read_file(self._blockchain_props['Private Key Path'])
        public_key = file.File.read_file(self._blockchain_props['Public Key Path'])
        keys = bigchaindb.loadkeys(private_key, public_key)

        logger.info('Connecting to RabbitMQ for %s Data Type' % self._queue)
        rabbit = rabbitMq.RabbitMq(self._rabbit_props,
                                   self._queue,
                                   bdb,
                                   keys)
        channel = rabbit.connect()
        rabbit.consume(channel)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    log = log.Logger('/etc/msdb/integration/logger.ini')
    log.load_config()
    logger = logging.getLogger('main')
    logger.info("Starting Mobile Subscriber Database Integration...")

    threads = []
    logger.debug("Created Empty Threads Array")

    logger.info("Loading Configuration")
    config = config.Config('/etc/msdb/integration/config.ini')
    properties = config.load_config()
    sections = config.get_sections(properties)

    logger.debug("Getting RabbitMQ Properties")
    Rabbit_Props = config.loadSection('RabbitMQ', properties)
    logger.debug("Getting Blockchain Properties")
    Blockchain_Props = config.loadSection('Blockchain', properties)

    logger.debug("Loading Data Type Properties")
    for section in sections:
        props = config.loadSection(section, properties)

        if (section != 'RabbitMQ') or (section != 'Blockchain'):
            logger.debug("Loading %s Properties" % section)
            if props.getboolean('Enabled'):
                logger.debug("Section Enabled, Creating Thread")
                threads.append(
                    ConsumerThread(
                        props['RabbitMQ Queue'],
                        props['Blockchain Hostname'],
                        int(props['Blockchain Port']),
                        Rabbit_Props,
                        Blockchain_Props
                    )
                )
            else:
                logger.debug("Section Disabled")

    logger.info("Starting Threads")
    for thread in threads:
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
    logger.info("Joining Threads")
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    exit(0)
```

Comment: Most likely, `integration` is located inside your PyCharm sandbox. Now that you're on the terminal, python looks to import modules in directories specified by `sys.path`, which your module isn't specified to be in.

Comment: can you do `cd /home/nathan/mobileSubscriberDB/integration/` and try ?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ from what I understand setting PYTHONPATH should get around this?

Comment: @MaheshKaria I will update the question, as I am already within that directory.

Comment: @NathanEnglish It should... did you 1) set it for the right version? 2) source your file?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ of course! PYTHONPATH will be using the default python on the OS.

Found this as a work around, what is your opinion? 
`ln -s /your/path /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

I haven't really used python in anger before.